# How these Jquery, ExtJs framework overwrite native Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I have seen the tutorial from ExtJs using the code as below:

```
 var myDiv = Ext.get('myDiv');
 myDiv.highlight();
```

where is hightlight() function from? Is it from native Javascript or ExtJs framework? I have done simple search but could not find it in API doc. If hightlight() is from ExtJs framework, how actually it overwrite the native behaviour in Javascript?

I wonder so how Jquery selector, let say `$('#myDiv')` can be recognized by Javascript? The $('') symbol shouldn't be recognized by Javascript compiler right?

My description is quite poor, sorry for that. I am javascript beginner.

Comment: `$` is an ordinary function.

Comment: This is a good read:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototype, Ext, etc. extend the prototype of the DOM objects (which is pretty [questionable behaviour](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/) by the way), e.g. `HTMLElement.prototype`, and add their own functions to it. That allows you to call them like shown in your example.

jQuery hovever doesn't use any magic at all. `$` is a normal identifier in JavaScript just like normal characters. So it's nothing but a function named `$` which you then call when doing `$('#selector')` etc. The return value of that function is usually a jQuery object which behaves like an array and has a ton of useful methods. So you never deal with the native DOM objects but just with an object *containing* one or more of them.

Comment: jQuery doesn't. jQuery wraps the original object instead.

Comment: I think IE won't let you extend `HTMLElement.prototype`. In FF and GC - no problem.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Initially he way only talking about ext. He apparently added the jQuery part later.

Comment: Since both Ext and also Prototype make extensive use of this I'm sure IE *does* allow extending those prototypes. It's just something that can easily break since since host object behaviour is not defined.

Comment: Prototype extends ECMAscript classes, not browser-provided classes. Browser-provided classes need not be extensible.

Comment: http://prototypejs.org/learn/extensions.html - it *does* extend DOM objects which are certainly not part of ECMAScript (because ECMAScript by itself doesn't even know what a DOM is)

Comment: This is really beyond my understanding. Does it mean that we can change how javascript parse the script?

Comment: @skyrim.ice you can't change the parsing process, but you can affect what methods are defined for which objects and which variables are defined in the global scope - and these variables can contain `$` and `_`.

Comment: @JanDvorak hi, I wonder native javascript shouldn't recognize $(#selector) right? How javascript recognize $('') ? I thought $ dollar sign only used in variable/identifier name?

Comment: @JanDvorak oh, after I read the answer so many times, I suddenly got the mind that $ sign is the function name! Am I right?

Comment: @skyrim.ice `$(#selector)` is a syntax error. `$("#selector")` is a function call to `$` (which is an alias for `jQuery`) with the argument `"#selector"`, which then delegates to `document.getElementById`, `document.querySelectorAll` or crawls the DOM manually. `$` is just a function name.

Comment: @skyrim.ice: JavaScript **IS NOT PHP**. In PHP you'd be right, `$` marks a variable. This is **not the case in JavaScript**. In JavaScript the `$` character is not different from characters like `a`, `b`, `c`, ...

Comment: @JanDvorak ok, I got it. For ExtJs, ThieftMaster said "extend the prototype of the DOM objects". So, we can extend the DOM object and add in the functions that we need? How can it be done? Is it complicated? Can you tell about the brief logic behind?

Comment: @skyrim.ice basically, it's just `HTMLElement.prototype.myFunc = ...`. The problem is, it works with `Array.prototype` but not with `HTMLElement.prototype` when `HTMLElement` is supplied by IE.

Comment: This is incorrect. Ext does NOT alter the DOM node API. Ext.get returns an Ext Element object that WRAPS a DOM node in a custom object, providing the API shown.  This answer is basically irrelevant to the original question.

Comment: -1; Ext JS does not alter DOM node prototype. This answer is incorrect and misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Ext provides an [Element](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element) object, which is what gets returned by calls like `Ext.get()`.  Element *wraps* DOM nodes, but most certainly does NOT alter the HTMLElement object (just like the jQuery $ function).  In fact, the [Element.dom](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-property-dom) property exposes the original unaltered DOM node.  [Element.highlight()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-highlight) is simply an Ext.Element method, and is documented clearly in the API docs -- there's nothing mysterious about it.

While Ext used to modify some native JS objects in previous versions (Date, String, Object) it has never touched the native HTMLElement object.  This used to be common practice among most JS libs, but as of version 4.0 (a couple of years now) Ext has not touched any native JS prototypes.